# Android device doesn't execute main thread (onTouchEvent) while drawing on the screen

Tags: android, performance, touch-event

everyone? 
I am testing some touch pad, which have to work with our company's android device. I implemented some drawing samples and run on android device. I implemented a lot of drawing samples.
When I run implemented apks on android mobiles or other devices, those were working perfectly.
But When runing on the our android device it draws on the screen after pen left the pad.
This is part of the one of drawing samples

```
public SignatureView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5.0f);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    debug("OnDraw");
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float eventX = event.getX();
    float eventY = event.getY();

    switch(event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        debug("ACTION_DOWN");
        path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
        lastTouchX = eventX;
        lastTouchY = eventY;
        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        debug("ACTION_MOVE");
        resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);
        path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        debug("ACTION_UP");
    break;
    default:
        return false;
    }
    invalidate(
            (int) (dirtyRect.left-halfStrokeWidth),
            (int) (dirtyRect.top-halfStrokeWidth),
            (int) (dirtyRect.right+halfStrokeWidth),
            (int) (dirtyRect.bottom+halfStrokeWidth));
    lastTouchX = eventX;
    lastTouchY = eventY;
    return true;
```

You can see on the log, it started drawing on the screen first but after while it didn't do anything, after pen left group of event occurs at same time, and after that it drew on the screen. I didn't make video but If you see, it is like nothing happened while I drawing, but after pen left events occured at same time.

What do you think what the problem is?Driver or sign pad or device. I don't know real spec of device, but I heard that the device spec is like samsung galaxy S1.

Answer (score 0):

onTouchEvent isn't executed on the mainThread. So just call

```
   activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // your drawing code here 
            resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
        }
    });
```

from inside the listener.